# Show different page on a page break in RTF template (BI publisher)

Tags: reporting, rtf, obiee, bi-publisher

I am trying to call a different page after every page break as shown below. The problem here is that my conditions (test2) can only be displayed within the same page as the header / total page but not break into a new page. I tried using (split-by-page-break) and even page braking the section, but all it does it appearing on the same page as the header.

> Header/Page1 (Countdown), followed by a Total/Page1 (test)
>
> Page break then Conditions/Page2 (Test2)
>
> Header/Page3 (Countdown), followed by a Total/Page3 (test)
>
> Page break then Conditions/Page4 (Test2)

```
<?template:countdown?>
Temp_Param
Recursive_Template
<?end template?>
**to call the total section** 
<?call-template:test?>
<?end body?> 
**this is to assign an after page break variable = 1**
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'Var', '1')?>
**to calculate the total section**
<?template:test?>
TOTAL   
<? format-number:Order_Total_Taxable_ID2;’999G999D99’?>     
<? format-number:Order_Total_Tax_ID3;’999G999D99’?> 
<?format-number:Order_Total_Gross_Amount_ID7;’999G999D99’?>
<?end template?>
**to call a different page**
<?if:xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'Var')='1'?>
<?call-template:test2?>
<?end if?>
**different page after every page break**
**need to break into a new page**
<?template:test2?>
CONDITIONS
This Purchase order is subject to the following terms and conditions:
1.PRICE
TEST
2.DELIVERIES
TEST
<?end template?>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are looking for. Maybe a visual representation would help? And/or a description of exactly what is on each page.

Answer (score 0):

Where you want the page break, try using this code:
     page

For more information, see this Oracle thread: https://community.oracle.com/thread/983330